# No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am changing the structure of my angular-4 app with lazy loaded modules and facing an error when I run

```
ng build
```

The error:

> Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency

This error do not appear when I am commenting out the lazy-loaded modules.

This is my *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "picosmos",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "papaparse": "4.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-less": "3.3.2",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "less": "2.7.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Global installed are (among others):

- TypeScript 2.4.2
- webpack 3.6.0
- @angular/cli 1.4.2

I found some issue Threads on GitHub, but no solutions helped me. I tried to reinstall `webpack` and `@angular/cli`. Nothing helped.

Any suggestions/experiences/tips with this?

---

This are my Route-Config for my `AppModule`

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

// These routes cause the compile-error (ng build)
  { path: "Finances", loadChildren: "./Finances/finances.module#FinancesModule" },
  { path: "Test", loadChildren: "./Test/test.module#TestModule" },
  { path: "Media", loadChildren: "./Media/media.module#MediaModule" },

//These routes work
  { path: "Dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: "Error/:errorId", component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "Dashboard"},
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/Error/http404" }
];
```

e.g. `test.module.ts`:

```
// imports

const testRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: IndexComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(
            testRoutes
        ),
        HttpModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        IndexComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        IndexComponent
    ]
})
export class TestModule {
}
```

Comment: Can you add reproduction? At least add the configuration of lazy loaded routes

Comment: @yurzui I added the route-config and one of the lazy-loaded sub-modules

Comment: Why do you use `"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4",` while other angular dependencies have `^4.2.4` version?

Comment: @yurzui it is not intended, I will try it with `"^4.2.4"`

Comment: @yurzui Thank you! That was the Problem...the unequal versions...
If you post it as a reply, I will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same versions of angular dependencies. So change:

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4"
```

to

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4"
```